# MultiSelect Filter Titles in JQuery Do not work

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am Using MultiLselect Filter in jquery and it sets the selected value in a hidden Filed ,Now I want to save the titles too and it do not give me any facility to to that :

```
 $("#" + targetDropdown).multiselect({
        header: ''
    });
    var target = $("#" + targetDropdown + '_con');

    $("#" + targetDropdown)
    .multiselect()
    .bind("multiselectclick multiselectcheckall multiselectuncheckall", function (event, ui) {

        checkedValues = $.map($(this).multiselect("getChecked"), function (input) {
            return input.value;
        });
        $("#" + targetDropdown + '_hid').val(
            checkedValues.length
                ? checkedValues.join(', ')
                : '---------'
        );
    })
    .triggerHandler("multiselectclick");

    $("#" + targetDropdown).multiselect().multiselectfilter();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Modified the above code you can use it directly and it will work instead of getting the value get the title